# Tree Nodes Getting Lost

Tags: c++, tree

So I'm trying to do an online assignment (this is not for course credit, I'm taking on my own through coursera) and I'm pretty confused with what's happening.

We are given an 2 line input. The first line is the number of vertices in the tree. The second line lists all the nodes parent nodes with -1 indicating it is the root.

For example, given the following input:

5

4 -1 4 1 1

The first line says there are 5 nodes in total. The second line says node 0 is a child of node 4, node 1
is the root, node 2 is a child of node 4, node 3 is a child of node 1 and node 4 is a child of node 1.

Right now I am just attempting to read in the input and store it in a tree structure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int key;
    vector<Node*> children;
};


void display(Node* root){
    cout << "My Value is " << root->key << endl;
    cout << "My children are ";
    for (int i = 0; i < root->children.size(); i++){
        cout << root->children[i]->key << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < root->children.size(); i++){
        display(root->children[i]);         //call display on all children
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){

    Node* root = NULL;
    int numOfNodes;
    cin >> numOfNodes;

    int input;
    vector<int> parents;
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfNodes; i++){
        cin >> input;
        parents.push_back(input);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < parents.size(); i++){
        Node *newNode = new Node();
        newNode->key = i;
        if(parents[i] == -1){ //root node is indicated with a -1 in input
            root = newNode;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < parents.size(); j++){
            if(parents[j] == i){
                Node *childNode = new Node();
                childNode->key = j;
                newNode->children.push_back(childNode);
                cout << "value " << newNode->key << " is now a parent of " << childNode->key << endl;
                //delete childNode;
            }
        }
    }
    display(root);

    return 0;
}
```

I added in the display function to see whether or not I was storing the tree correctly and this is where I'm lost.  The print statements I added seem to be conflicting.  In main I added a cout whenever I added a childNode however by the time my program gets to the display function is seems the childNodes are missing with the exeception of the children of the root node.  Here is a sample of my output.

```
./treeheight
5
4 -1 4 1 1
value 1 is now a parent of 3
value 1 is now a parent of 4
value 4 is now a parent of 0
value 4 is now a parent of 2
My Value is 1
My children are 3 4 
My Value is 3
My children are 

My Value is 4
My children are
```

It would seem that creation of the tree in main worked as I wanted it to but when I try to reference those same nodes in display something is going wrong that I do not understand.  I would have thought the output in display would read

```
My Value is 1
My children are 3 4 
My Value is 3
My children are 

My Value is 4
My children are 2 0
```

If anyone could shed some light on what's going on here I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `Node *newNode = new Node();` -- Looking at your code, you do nothing to store this pointer if `if(parents[i] == -1)` is false.  Thus a memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `i == 2`, you create a node `Node(1)`, and the inner loop finds the two children `Node(3)` and `Node(4)`. This gives you the following structure:

```
            Node(1)
             /   \
        Node(3) Node(4)
```

Then you save this structure in `root`. So this is saved. Afterwards, when `i == 3`, you create a new node `Node(3)`. Notice: this is not the same node is the node `Node(3)` in the tree starting in `root`. They have the same key, but they are two completely different nodes.

The same thing happens, when `i == 4`. You create a new node `Node(4)`, which has two children. But this is not the same node as in the tree. It's a `new` node. And because you don't save the new node with the children `Node(0)` and `Node(1)` anywhere, this node gets deleted.

So at the end, you only have the `root` node and both it's children.

For a solution: you have to store each node somewhere. Don't throw them away. And don't recreate new nodes, when you already created them somewhere. For instance you could create all nodes using a initial for loop and save them in a temporary vector. And afterwards, you copy the pointers to the children-vectors.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I understand the flaw in my logic you've spotted but I'm not sure I understand how to fix it.  I tried creating a temporary vector like you suggested but now all the "connections" are stored in that vector correct? i.e when I try to call my display function Node(4) is a different Node(4) then the one my root node is pointing to. I am not sure how to actually add the children to the correct Node (4) (the one my root node is pointing to).

Comment: See at the solution of @MatthewFisher. His implementation is exactly what I meant.

Comment: Thank you, I understand his method.  I just would to know for my own knowledge how I would accomplish what I just described above.  If I were to continue using my "pointer" method how would I assign the children to the correct node, instead of a new node that is not connected to root

Comment: @EricS You have to store the intermediate nodes somewhere. You could for instance use a `vector<Node*>`. And before the creation of a node in your for loops, you ask if it is already created: `if (vec[i] == nullptr) new_node = vec[i] = new Node(); else new_node = vec[i];`

Comment: Or use a completely different approach: generate the nodes recursively with a function `generateTree(Node *root)`. Start this function with the root node. In this function you search for all the children nodes, add them to `root->children` and then call `generateTree(child)` for each child.

Answer (score 2):

Coursera rocks!

Allocating the nodes and wiring them up at the same time is confusing your algorithm.  I split the two tasks apart and the result appear to work as expected.  This is often a good design pattern, separate tasks and do each independently.

Error checking is limited so garbage input will likely result in a crash.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int key;
    vector<Node*> children;
};


void display(Node* root){
    cout << "My Value is " << root->key << endl;
    cout << "My children are ";
    for (int i = 0; i < root->children.size(); i++){
        cout << root->children[i]->key << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < root->children.size(); i++){
        display(root->children[i]);         //call display on all children
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){

    Node* root = NULL;
    int numOfNodes;
    vector<Node> nodes;
    cin >> numOfNodes;

    int input;
    vector<int> parents;
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfNodes; i++){
        cin >> input;
        parents.push_back(input);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < parents.size(); i++)  // make a vector of nodes for storage
       nodes.push_back(Node());

    for(int i = 0; i < parents.size(); i++){
        nodes[i].key = i;  // set the key on each
        if(parents[i] == -1){ //root node is indicated with a -1 in input
            root = &nodes[i];
        }
        else
        {
           nodes[parents[i]].children.push_back(&nodes[i]);  // set parent
        }
    }
    display(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `root = &nodes[i];` and this:  `nodes[parents[i]].children.push_back(&nodes[i]);`  This doesn't look good.  A vector will invalidate iterators when resized, thus your `root` may be garbage by the time this is executed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The root is pointing to the nodes vector while the push back is on a different vector in particular node.  Good point though about vectors and pointers

Comment: Of course, the easiest fix is to change to `std::list<Node>` if invalidation were to occur.