# My tree-node has a missing link

Tags: c++, c++11

I was going through the question [Tree Nodes Getting Lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045146/tree-nodes-getting-lost/39045454#39045454) and thought it woudl be a good exercise to do in c++11.

I came with the code below. But the Root element is not connecting to the rest of the nodes and I can't find why.

Edit: you can find the code here: https://ideone.com/NCyRsx I use visual studio but I obtain the same results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

struct Node 
{
    int key;
    std::vector<Node> children;
    Node(int k)
    {
        key = k;
    }

    void Add(Node n)
    {
        children.push_back(n);
    }

    void display()
    {
        std::cout << "My value is " << key << std::endl;
        std::cout << "My " << children.size()  << " kid(s) are : " << std::endl;
        for( auto n : children)
        {
            n.display();
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    constexpr int numNode = 5; // for 
    std::array<int, numNode> numbers = { 4, -1, 4, 1, 1 }; 
    std::vector<Node> nodesStorage;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numNode ; i++)
    {
        nodesStorage.push_back(Node(i));
    }
    nodesStorage.push_back(Node(-1)); 

    for (int i = 0 ; i< numNode ; i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i] == -1) // the root
        {
            nodesStorage[numNode].Add(nodesStorage[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            nodesStorage[numbers[i]].Add(nodesStorage[i]);
        }
    }

    nodesStorage[1].display();
    nodesStorage[numNode].display();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Would you post the output of the code? I suspect the `Node`s being copied around `Add` calls is the cause.

Comment: One problem is, I would say, that `children` contains ***copies*** of nodes. Not e.g. pointers to the nodes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg well i don't think so as the node 4 is updated after being added into children. but for some reason it seems to be the case for the root node. Which is why I am confused.

Comment: That's because children are added to their parent _after_ they are updated. Consider i == 4; here, numbers[i] == 1 and it means `nodesStorage[1].Add(nodesStorage[4])`, and at this point nodesStorage[4] is already updated at i == 0 and i == 2. I succeeded to get desired results using pointers. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Node::Add` calls in `main` updates `Node`s in `nodesStorage` but not `Node::children` (and vice versa) because `Node`s are passed by value (i.e. copied). As pointed out in the comments, you have to use pointers instead of values.

Replace

```
std::vector<Node> nodesStorage;
```

by

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodesStorage;
```

and fix everywhere else your compiler complains about. Oh, and make sure you `#include <memory>`.

Since you are doing this as an exercise, I'm leaving out detailed fixes for now. Here are references for [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

In C++11 (or rather C++14) we rarely handle raw pointers, `new` or `delete` operators. Instead we use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` depending on needs. `std::shared_ptr` calls `delete` in its destructor when no other `std::shared_ptr` refers the same object. This ensures a resource is automatically disposed when it is no longer needed (RAII idiom).